# Eclipse error - Cannot be resolved to type

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

Created a Maven Project and have set the dependencies in the pom.xml. The import statement (com.splunk.*) seems to recognize the library included in the Maven Dependencies, however when I refer to the class (for e.g. ResultsReaderXml) within that library, it shows the "error message cannot be resolved to type". Can some please explain why Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) is doing that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/enCRW.png

Comment: Did you do a  maven/update in Eclipse ? Do the dependency JARs show up in the dependencies tree ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that many times earlier and it didn't help.  Yes, the "splunk : 1.5.0.0" appears in the Dependency Hierarchy of pom.xml.  I have been able to work with Maven project that directly downloads from Maven Repository, but when I use a different external repository, I am experiencing this issue.  The Maven is able to download the jar locally, but strangely it behaves as if there is no jar in the Maven Dependencies. <pre>   <repository>
   <id>ext-release-local</id>
   <url>http://splunk.artifactoryonline.com/splunk/ext-releases-local</url>
  </repository> </pre>

Comment: The jar is downloaded locally, you say, but... is it well-formed? Can you open it with a Zip File Manager and see the classes within, with the proper file structure?

Comment: Thanks Little, that resolved the issue.  I do wanted to let you know that the file is accessible with 7-zip file manager.  However, I couldn't validate all the folder navigations.  I tried uncompressing, which typically completes but then I observed it was getting stuck at 45%.  I removed the dependency from pom.xml, removed the splunk folder from the repository.  After adding the dependency again, the class got validated successfully.